# Baking AO onto a Prop with moving parts

Tags: texture-baking

How would you go about that? For my example I have this clock.
[image]

Here is when I bake the AO map, youll see the clock hands get baked onto the face of the clock. (Right pic). How do I set up my low and high poly models so I can bake the AO from everything while exluding the clock hands.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new collection and move the hands into it.

Then uncheck everything as done in the image for the collection "buttons":

[image]

Bake the AO.

When you want the hands, you can turn on the collection.